# Integrating angular 2 with laravel 5.2

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, frontend, backend

I am new to Laravel and want to integrate Angular 2 (front-end framework) with Laravel 5.2 (back-end framework) on web applications.

I have the following queries:

- Where do I put the front end files?
- How to implement user authentications?

Answer (score 5):

With this stack, you code your backend as an API more or less like [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). And the front end accesses that API. So your front-end and back-end can stay anywhere.

So, you can place your front-end files in your laravel project or you can create a separate project for front-end and back-end. If you choose to serve your angular application from laravel application, you have to configure your angular application routes along with laravel routes. Most of the angular files will reside in `public folder` of your laravel application.

[image: laravel_folder]

For user authentication, you can set up JWT (JSON Web Tokens) or [OAuth](https://medium.com/@barryvdh/oauth-in-javascript-apps-with-angular-and-lumen-using-satellizer-and-laravel-socialite-bb05661c0d5c). You can use an angular package called `Satelizer`.

You can make the front end site on main domain like http://example.com whereas the backend on a subdomain like http://api.example.com and the communication can involve URL white-listing and JWTs to prevent the unauthorized access to API.